# How do you get rocket boots in Candy Box 2?

Tags: candy-box-2

I've looked about everywhere and can't find them. I've checked the witches place, merchant, blacksmith, the mountain pass, the hole, and the ocean, though I can't get too far in the ocean because of my health. I want to use them to pass over the gates to the castle. Does anyone know where they are? I can't find any questions for them.

Comment: why is this getting downvoted?

Comment: Can you please perhaps explain where exactly you've looked to your answer? It helps us and future readers understand your question.

Comment: @OKprogrammer Do you mean, where I have looked for the rocket boots or where I have looked for answers?

Comment: I mean where you have looked in the game.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for telling me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

room 3 in the desert temple. make stairs out of warriors summoned by the enchanted tribal spear. once you get the rocket boots you can beat the first room easily. there is no point to breaking the teapot in teh second room.